# Hanging a curtain rod to hold Drapes on an Old Plaster wall (which wall has no studs)

Tags: walls

Help, a novice here.  What is the best way to mount/attach a rod to hold heavy drapes to an old plaster wall.  The wall is an exterior wall that has no studs (i.e., it is the wall that faces the back yard).

The bracket will be at least 8 feet in width and hold heavy living room drapes.  I've read that it's best to use toggle or molly bolts - but that doesn't make sense as the wall is entirely made of plaster. In other words, there is no way to get behind the plaster as the entire wall is plaster until you hit the outside brick wall?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of your wall (inside and out), or a diagram of how it is built, would help us help you.

Comment: Is there a window frame? What's it made of on top and sides?